# How to solve pcl/kdtree/kdtree_ann.h not found?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [find_object](http://www.ros.org/wiki/find_object).

I download:

```
 svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/find_object
 svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/point_cloud_perception_experimental/point_cloud_python
```

And I rosmake,it shows:

```
  In file included from /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/find_object/table_boundary_detector/src/table_boundary_node.cpp:1:
    /home/sam/code/ros/sam_perception/find_object/table_boundary_detector/include/table_boundary_node.hh:23: fatal error: pcl/kdtree/kdtree_ann.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

I try to install PCL,but not works:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37917/how-to-solve-pcl/kdtree/kdtree_ann.h-not-found?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package `find_object` is really old and I wouldn't expect it to work without investing quite some time fixing it. Your current problem seems to be that your PCL version is much more recent than what `find_object` expects. That means you'll have to fix `find_object` to work with the newer PCL version.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-07-04**:
Is there any package to replace find_object? Or how to fix that problem? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-04**:
I don't know about any other package that provides the same functionality in such an integrated way. But you have the source code of `find_object` so can try fixing it and upgrading it to the new PCL version.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-07-05**:
Yeah, I post the original question because I don't know how to fix it. Is there any solutions? Thank you~